# $.connection.(hubname) is undefined. Signalr/hub 501(not implemented)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a MVC 4 application which has a register page.

The code for hub is as follows:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SignalR.Hubs;

[HubName("messageHub")]
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Broadcast the message to all clients
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">message to be broadcasted</param>
    public void Broadcast(string message, string messagetype, string messagetitle)
    {
        this.Clients.showMessage(message, messagetype, messagetitle);
    }
    public void Getsubscription()
    {

    }
}
```

Similarly, the JS hub code is:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js")"></script>
<script src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>Index</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Initialize hub
        var hub = $.connection.messageHub;

        // hub.start();
        $.connection.hub.start();
        //Append event to Button
        //hub.broadcast("c","b","a");

    });

</script>
```

Now, after running it is get $.connection.messageHub as undefined

[image: Screenshot in debug mode]

secondly my chrome network shows;-
[image: Network -Chrome]

Thirdly, when clicking on initiator for signalr/hub i get not implemented error:-
[image]

I have tried changing the URL's for scripts, also ran as IIS but couldn't get it working.
If i keep my scripts in .cshtml (View) and change --> use Local IIS Webserver, its working fine
Any help.!

Comment: I assume you are including the base jQuery library as well? And also, is $.connection defined?

Comment: If you navigate to that url manually in the browser what does it show?

Comment: @AndersHolmström I have pasted the response for connection in my 1st screenshot. Just wanted to update that, if i keep my scripts in .cshtml (View) and change use Local IIS Webserver, its working fine!

Answer (score 3):

> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
>
> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

commented this section out in layout section and worked for me.

Comment: so signalr is not compatible with bundles yet?

Comment: Bundles are loaded at compile time but `/signalr/hubs` is generated at runtime. i think that is why using bundle is not working in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding reference to `/signalr/hubs` in bundle config dose not work because it is generated at run-time and bundling happens at compile-time.
so i did this:
1- created a section like this in each view i need to have reference to `signalr/hubs`:

```
    @section SignalRScripts{
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    }
```

2- in my layout file after rendering all other scripts, rendered this section:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/js")  
    @RenderSection("SignalRScripts", required: false)  
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

then it worked fine.